# Collect List<Object> to Map<String, List<Object>> in Java 8 using stream

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to do this iteration using java 8 stream instead of traditional for loop.

I have a List of Object `List<Obligation>`
and the `Obligation` is having `List` of `String` within.

`Obligation` contains fields like

`f1` and `f2` of type `String`,

and

`f3` of type `List<String>`

What I want to achieve is `Map<String, List<Obligation>>` such that, `String` used in key of `Map` is each value present in `List<String>` from each `Obligation` within `List<Obligation>`

This is how the code would look in traditional for loop:

```
// newly initialized Map
Map<String, List<Obligation>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Obligation>>();

// assume the list is populated
List<Obligation> obligations = someMethod();

                for(Obligation obligation : obligations) {
                    for(String license : obligation.getLicenseIDs()) {
                        if(map.containsKey(license)) {
                            map.get(license).add(obligation);
                        } else {
                            List<Obligation> list = new ArrayList<Obligation>();
                            list.add(obligation);
                            map.put(license, list);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The question is well explained, good efforts from a newbie here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to create a stream of pairs of `Obligation` and license IDs, and then use `groupingBy` to collect them by license ID.

```
Map<String, List<Obligation>> map =
    obligations.stream() // Stream<Obligation>
               .flatMap(o -> o.getLicenseIDs()
                              .stream()
                              .map(id -> new SimpleEntry<>(o,id))) // Stream<Map.Entry<Obligation,String>>
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                              Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                                 Collectors.toList())));
```